# How to use {} curly bracket in Sitecore emails?

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore-exm

Sitecore sends the same email template to different users. By using the user's name with `{}`. For example, **Dear {Name}..** In place of Name it should be a certain user's name. Can someone help how to do it in Sitecore?

Comment: It's `$firstname$` or `$lastname$` in Sitecore EXM

Answer (score 1):

The Email Experience Manager (EXM) supports tokens that you can use to personalise your email campaign messages. The following tokens are by default available in EXM:

- $email$
- $fullname$
- $firstname$
- $lastname$
- $name$
- $phone$

More helpful information you can read [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/users/exm/102/email-experience-manager/insert-a-token-in-a-message.html).